# Let A be an $m \times n$ totally unimodular matrix. Show that its transpose is also totally unimodular

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

> Let A be an $m \times n$ totally unimodular matrix. Show that its transpose is also totally unimodular

Why is this true? I dont know how to prove it? With the theorem that each column contains at most two non-zero entries, and that there is a partition of the rows?

Comment: You could write the question in the body, not in the title, and explain the terms you are using ("totally unimodular", "inimodular" etc.).

Comment: @Thomas Andrews A totally unimodular matrix need not be square https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix#Total_unimodularity

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Whoops, yes. I assumed a matrix which is totally unimodular was unimodular.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a matrix, then $\text{det}(A^T) = \text{det}(A)$. Apply this fact to the definition of totally unimodular matrix.